# Get text for each class of the same and set it as a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, for-loop, each

Currently I have set each and every variable manually, though I would like it to do this automaticaly.

This is my current code:

```
    var homePos = $('#btn_home').offset();
    var homeWidth = $('#btn_home').outerWidth();
    var homeArrow = homePos.left + ( homeWidth / 2) - bodyWidth / 2;

    var serverPos = $('#btn_server').offset();
    var serverWidth = $('#btn_server').outerWidth();
    var serverArrow = serverPos.left + ( serverWidth / 2) - bodyWidth / 2;

    var infoPos = $('#btn_info').offset();
    var infoWidth = $('#btn_info').outerWidth();
    var infoArrow = infoPos.left + ( infoWidth / 2) - bodyWidth / 2;
```

Notice that I basicly repeat the same thing with different names and ids.

I have multiple classes set up with different texts, such as these:

```
    <div class="btn a" id="btn_Home">Home</div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn_Info">Info</div>
```

So I though I could use the texts and create the variables from it, but I am not sure how to.
I think I could do something with this, but I am not sure how to continue from here:

```
    $('.btn').each(function() {
    var btnText = $(this).text();
    });
```

Comment: You're creating lots of variables, but what are you actually doing with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just wanted arrows:

```
var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
var arrows={};
$('.btn').each(function() {
    var btnText = $(this).text();
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    arrows[btnText]=pos.left + ( width / 2) - bodyWidth / 2;
});
```

And if you wanted others vars too:

```
var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
var vars={};
$('.btn').each(function() {
    var btnText = $(this).text();
    vars[btnText]={};
    vars[btnText]['pos'] = $(this).offset();
    vars[btnText]['width'] = $(this).outerWidth();
    vars[btnText]['arrow']=vars[btnText]['pos'].left + ( vars[btnText]['width'] / 2) - bodyWidth / 2;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Store your data into an object:

```
var data = {}

// catch all elements whose ID starts with btn_
$('[id^="btn_"]').each(function(){

  data[this.id.split('btn_').pop()] = {
    'pos' : $(this).offset(),
    'width' : $(this).outerWidth(),
    ... : ...
  }

});
```

This way you can refer to `data['Home']` or `data['Info']`.

Comment: You want an object, not an array.  `var data = {};`.  Also, why did you change the selector from `$('.btn')`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat because you may want to have `.btn` stuff which does not belong to this collection - I would just rely on a `data-*` attr better, but that's OP matter then.

Comment: Then add a class just for this, what if you have `btn_` stuff that doesn't belong?

Comment: @RocketHazmat if you just rely on the class name, you won't be able to name the object into `data`. As I said, I would just rely on a `data-*` attribute better in order to avoid such collisions.

Comment: Huh?  What does "won't be able to name the object into data" mean?  You can still do `this.id` id you used `$('.btn').each`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `data[someUniqueKey]` - if you just rely on the class, how would you store data into the hash?

Comment: By getting the element's id, the same way you currently are!  You are still getting an *ELEMENT*, you are just querying for it differently.

Comment: @RocketHazmat that's why I changed the selector: to be sure to deal with buttons with such id pattern - with all chance the OP is using Bootstrap, and may have other `.btn` elements around. Anyway got your point.

Comment: Ah.  Ok, I understand now.  Sorry :-)

Comment: If I would use this, how do I call for example the variable 'pos' for Home?

Comment: @user2501582 `data['Home'].pos`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function would would create a store of values for you. I'm not sure this will save you much code if you only have to do this three times, though:

```
var values = {};
var bodyWidth = $('body').width();

function addValues(key) {
    var $el = $('#btn_' + key);
    var offset = $el.offset();
    var outerWidth = $el.outerWidth();

    values[key + 'Pos'] = offset;
    values[key + 'Width'] = outerWidth;
    values[key + 'Arrow'] = offset.left + ( outerWidth / 2) - bodyWidth / 2;
}

addValues('home');
addValues('server');
addValues('info');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yXYq6/2

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Then all your data is in 1 variable:

```
var data = {};
$(function(){
  var id, pos, width;
  function process( selector ) {
    $(selector).each(function() {
      data[id = $(this).attr('id')] = {
        pos: pos = $(this).offset(),
        width: width = $(this).outerWidth(),
        arrow: pos.left + ( width / 2) - width / 2,
      };
    });
  }
  process( '.btn' );
  console.log(data);
});
```